# It seems that Thread.start() doesn't call the run method

Tags: android, multithreading

```
private void showLocation(final Location location){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                StringBuilder url=new StringBuilder();
                url.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=");
                url.append(location.getLatitude());
                url.append(",");
                url.append(location.getLongitude());
                url.append("&sensor=false");
                URL Url=new URL(url.toString());
                connection=(HttpURLConnection)Url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(8000);
                InputStream in=connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder response=new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    response.append(line);
                }
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response.toString());
                JSONArray resultArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                if(resultArray.length()>0){
                    JSONObject subObject=resultArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    String address=subObject.getString("formatted_address");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Message message=new Message();
                    message.what=SHOW_LOCATION;
                    message.obj=address;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if(connection!=null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                    connection=null;
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

I use this method to show detail information about position via using Goole map Api. 
But it seems that the run() is never called due to the App's activity.
I have searched the problem but didn't fix it.
I'm new to andoird and I can't find the bug. Need help.

Comment: remove it.. `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: You can not update UI from a non UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your log. My guess is that there is an error because you are trying to create a Toast from a thread. For the Toast command, and all other calls that affects the ui, you should wrap it in runOnUiThread().

Comment: I use Log.d instead of Toast and it proved the run method is actually called.Though the UIwidget still doesn't work correctly, at least I know the problem is not because run method isn't called. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not update UI from a non UI thread.You need to remove your Toast call.
try this..

```
private void showLocation(final Location location){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                StringBuilder url=new StringBuilder();
                url.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=");
                url.append(location.getLatitude());
                url.append(",");
                url.append(location.getLongitude());
                url.append("&sensor=false");
                URL Url=new URL(url.toString());
                connection=(HttpURLConnection)Url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setConnectTimeout(8000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(8000);
                InputStream in=connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder response=new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    response.append(line);
                }
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response.toString());
                JSONArray resultArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                if(resultArray.length()>0){
                    JSONObject subObject=resultArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    String address=subObject.getString("formatted_address");
                    Log.e("address",address);
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Message message=new Message();
                    message.what=SHOW_LOCATION;
                    message.obj=address;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if(connection!=null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                    connection=null;
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

and see the logs.. notice the tag "address".